# Payload Empty when Passing in Non-Restful Action in Backbone

Tags: backbone.js

How do I pass in data when I need to POST to a non-restful action within the Model?

For Example...

module.exports = Base.extend( {

```
url: {
    'create': '/sites/:site_id/footer',
    'update': '/sites/:site_id/footers/:activity',
    'copy': '/sites/:site_id/:language/:label/footer/copy',
    'delete': '/sites/:site_id/footer/:id'
},

api: 'service',

copy: function () {
    var new_label = this.get( 'label' ) + ' Copy';


    return this.save( {}, {
        type: 'POST',
        url: this._getUrl( 'copy' ),
        data: JSON.stringify( {
            action: 'copy',
            label: new_label
        } )
    } );
}
```

} );

Problem is that whenever we pass in the data...  payload only shows 'action'. Label is completely ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
copy: function () {
     var new_label = this.get( 'label' ) + ' Copy';

     return this.sync(
         'create',
         this,
         {
             url: this._getUrl( 'copy' ),
             attrs: {
                  action: 'copy',
                  label: new_label
             }
         }
     );
 }
```

This is basically the magic behind the `save` function without all the auto collection the data to send. Note the if you use the `attrs` key in the options then you don't need to `stringify` the data yourself as it will be done for you in the sync method.